# Two different date fields want to check is gte or lte

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Am new to Elasticsearch `6.2.1` and Kibana `6.2.1`. Now am working on scripted Field in kibana.
I have two different date fields in indices like (resolved_on and resolve_due_by) i want check the condition if resolved_on is lessThan or equalTo resolve_due_bye. I tried some scripted query that are shown below

```
doc['resolved_on'] <= doc['resolve_due_by']  <!-- This not working -->
```

The below code is working now. I don't know whether it's correct way or not to proceed two dates.

```
((doc['resolved_on'].date.dayOfYear <= doc['resolve_due_by'].date.dayOfYear) && (doc['resolved_on'].date.millisOfDay <= doc['resolve_due_by'].date.millisOfDay))
```

Please can anyone help me this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution of my question. the working code is below

```
(((!doc['resolved_on'].empty) && (doc['resolved_on'].value.getMillis() > doc['resolve_due_by'].value.getMillis())))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.2/painless-examples.html#modules-scripting-painless-dates), in the painless scripting language, date fields are exposed as ReadableDateTime

> Date fields are exposed as `ReadableDateTime` so they support methods like getYear, and getDayOfWeek. **To get milliseconds since epoch call getMillis**

And they give the following example

```
GET hockey/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "birth_year": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc.born.value.year"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have the `getMillis`, you are back to comparing `long` values.

Furthermore, as I assume this is a JodaTime class (for full documentation, see [Joda Time API documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableDateTime.html)), you could also used  `isBefore()` or `isAfter()` methods.

Comment: thanks for answer. I found the solution to this question and i posted answer.